# AngularJs Call a function when 2 different https requests are done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-scope

Suppose i have 2 http requests, that i want both to be called asynchronously but i want both of them be finished before i'm rendering my view, how can i condition 2 separate calls to be done in order to call one function.
call3 and call4 are still running in the background but i don't want to wait for them to finish.

i added a sample code:

```
var call1_done = false;
var call2_done = false;
var call3_done = false;
var call4_done = false;

API.get_client().then(function(){
    call1_done = true;
});

API.get_all_clients().then(function(){
    call2_done = true;
});

// ignore call3 and call4 they can continue in the background
if (call1_done && call2_done)
{
   render_the_page();
}
```

Comment: Check out `$q.all()`.

Comment: @zsong not good enough cause i have more calls i have 4 calls but i want to render the view after call1 and call2 are done, i don't mind about call3 and call 4 won't finish by then

Comment: please update your question with that info because on first view its classic `$q.all([])`

Comment: What's wrong with using $q.all but only passing in a promise for call1 and call2? That will resolve as soon as those two are done without waiting for call3 or call4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't interesting to use `$q.all([])`, I would try to use `$watch`.

```
 $scope.calls = {
   call1_done: false,
   call2_done: false
 };



API.get_client().then(function(){
    $scope.calls.call1_done = true;
});

API.get_all_clients().then(function(){
    $scope.calls.call2_done = true;
});

/* 2 and 4 async tasks are running ..... */

 $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.calls;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue.call1_done && newValue.call2_done ){
      render_the_page();
     }
}, true);
```

Here we listen on one object that stores two flags and if both flags turn to `true` -> fire `render_the_page()`

Comment: what are "newValue" and "oldValue" got to do here?

Comment: Its only verification to avoid watch if old aka previous value and new one are equal. basically you can add check like: `if(newValue == oldValue) return; `

Comment: but you don't user oldValue inside the function

Comment: right, there is several forms of $watch, you can use one of them